# yii-auth: Where I should add bizrule to new Task?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, rbac

Im trying to use RBAC in my app with Auth extension. I was able to add hierarchy by 
GUI provided by extension like here:
[image]

What Im trying to do now is adding bizRule to updateOwnPost.
According to [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/136/getting-to-understand-hierarchical-rbac-scheme/) I need to add some code:

```
$auth=Yii::app()->authManager;

$auth->createOperation('createPost','create a post');
$auth->createOperation('readPost','read a post');
$auth->createOperation('updatePost','update a post');
$auth->createOperation('deletePost','delete a post');

$bizRule='return Yii::app()->user->id==$params["post"]->authID;';
$task=$auth->createTask('updateOwnPost','update a post by author himself',$bizRule);
$task->addChild('updatePost');

$role=$auth->createRole('reader');
$role->addChild('readPost');

$role=$auth->createRole('author');
$role->addChild('reader');
$role->addChild('createPost');
$role->addChild('updateOwnPost');

$role=$auth->createRole('editor');
$role->addChild('reader');
$role->addChild('updatePost');

$role=$auth->createRole('admin');
$role->addChild('editor');
$role->addChild('author');
$role->addChild('deletePost');
```

But we can see this code is creating new operation/task/roles. I've added them by GUI.
So what I need now is place to place something like:

```
$bizRule='return Yii::app()->user->id==$params["post"]->authID;';
```

to created earlier updateOwnPost Task.

Ofc my luck headed me only to this topic: [link](https://github.com/Crisu83/yii-auth/issues/16) where m-nel said:

> This question was answered in the comments section of the extension's
>   page. Read: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/auth/#c11261

and ofc comment I need is flushed out of space :)

Could someone answer me what should I do, to provide bizrule to Task?
Thank you ;)
(and sorry 4 my eng)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This add a bizrule to a task and add a child (operation) to it.

```
$bizRule='return Yii::app()->user->id==$params["post"]->authID;'; // here goes the bizrule
$task=$auth->createTask('updateOwnPost','update a post by author himself',$bizRule); // here we create a task and attach the bizrule
$task->addChild('updatePost'); // here we attach the operation to it
```

So, you need to make a test on your code to perform the access check, something like:

```
$params=array('post'=>$this->loadPost($id));
if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('updateOwnPost',$params))
{
    // update post
}
```

You can add this snippet to a filter or inside your action do perform the check.
I think it would be easier to make small checks to make sure that the User can edit the post. First check if the User is an author and then check if he can edit that post. Filters are a bit more complex.